# Adding transitions for custom Item

Tags: c++, animation, qml, qt5, transition

I have a simple QML code like this:

```
GridView {
    id: viewId

    anchors.fill: parent

    delegate: delegateId
    cellWidth: 100
    cellHeight: 100    
}

Component {
    id: delegateId

    Rectangle {
        id: rectId

        width:  100
        height: 100

        MyCystomItem {
            id: imageId
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: parent.height
            width:  parent.width

            myCustomProperty: myCustomRole                
        }
    }
}
```

In delegate I use `MyCustomItem` which is defined on c++ side of my project.
When `MyCustomItem::paint()` is called for the first time I paint some 'wait' indicator, 
and using value passed to `myCustomProperty` I begin some calculations on a thread.
When calculations are done, I call `MyCustomItem::update()` and I paint result of calculations.

I'd like to experiment with `QtQuick`'s transitions to make the grid more alive so I though
about adding some transition between 'wait' and 'final result` states. It is not important which one, 
the problem is I do not know what would be the right way of doing this.
I'd like to avoid any timer based attempts in my c++ code. I'd like to place transitions 
directly in qml file so I can easliy experiment with various effects.

Next step would be to add transitions to item when 'wait' state is active.
What would be the most qml-like approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what exactly you want to animate. But I'll try to give some idea's

### Option 1

You could expose the internal state of the custom item, with properties like `waiting` (or better `working`) and `done`. In QML you can bind to these properties in `State` [objects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html) and `Transition` [objects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transition.html):

```
MyCystomItem {
    id: imageId
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    height: parent.height
    width:  parent.width

    myCustomProperty: myCustomRole

    states: [
        State {
            name: "working"
            when: imageId.working && !imageId.done
            //you could set properties
        },
        State {
            name: "done"
            when: !imageId.working && imageId.done
            //you could set properties
        }
    ],
    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "*"
            to: "working" //here goes the name from the state
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "x,y";
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad;
                duration: 200;
            }                
        }
    ]      
}
```

### Option 2

Depending on what the calculations are you could add one or more properties that represent the results and use `Behavior` objects. Since you id'd the custom item `imageId`, I don't think you are really interested in this option, but just putting it here for completenes.

Note also, that this option exposes a bit of an issue with mixed responsibilities ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)); The calculations are done in the same class as the representation. So in the code below I'm assuming the MyCustomItem is only doing the calculation (as soon as it's instantiated)

```
Rectangle {
    id: tempView
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    height: parent.height
    width:  parent.width

    color: imageId.working ? "transparent" 
                           : imageId.temperature < 20 ? "blue" : "red"
    Behavior on color { ColorAnimation { duration: 500 } }

    MyCystomItem {
        id: imageId
    }
}
```

### Option 3

Lastly, you could make the grid a bit more alive with `ProgressBar`s. For this it is needed to have an idea on how far the calculation is, and of course expose that value

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

MyCystomItem {
    id: imageId
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    height: parent.height
    width:  parent.width


    ProgressBar {
       anchors.left: parent.left
       anchors.right: parent.right
       anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
       value: imageId.progress
       visible: imageId.progress < 100
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

I think the most valuable part in this answer it to expose your internal calculation state to the QML side with Q_PROPERTY's. Since you can only control what is visible.